# Evaluating search engines : free alternatives for TREC

Tags: search, open-source, search-engine

I am evaluating several open-source search engines with each other. I wanted to do this using the TREC data collections such as WT10G or an enterprise data collection...

But seems like most of the datasets are very expensive (500£ for WT10G). That is why I wanted to ask if there are free TREC data collections which can be used with open-source search engines such as Lucene? If not, is there are other data collections with the same quality of TREC but free?

Answer (score 3):

The venerable [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_Information_Retrieval_System) system comes with a bunch of test collections with labeled queries, e.g. [one compiled from CACM papers](ftp://ftp.cs.cornell.edu/pub/smart/cacm/). These collections aren't necessarily free in the sense of a permission to distribute (modified) versions for any purpose, but they're available at no cost. You might need to do some work to decipher the file formats, but they're plain text and documented.

[MS Research has also released test corpora](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/mslr/) for non-commercial use, actually intended for learning to rank experiments but potentially useful for more general IR development.

Comment: Thanks, the FTP link does not work for me but the data from MS Research looks pretty ok. Ill download and let you know. Do you maybe know of TREC collections where you can directly download it without them sending you a hdd or cd rom? Does not matter if it requires a fee but just need it relatively quick :)

Comment: @Merlijn: no idea, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the suggestions

Comment: @FredFoo : can LETOR dataset be used to evaluate an information retrieval system (VSM using a modified tf-idf) ? I mean, does it have a ground truth (queries and relevant documents.. etc)